# Cancel click handler from mousedown handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handlers

I’m trying to prevent a click handler from firing based on a condition inside the mousdown handler for the same element. Consider this:

```
var bool = true;

$('button').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
}).mousedown(function(e) {
  bool = !bool;
  if ( bool ) {
    // temporary prevent the click handler, how?
  }
});
```

Is there a neat way to cross-communicate between handlers? Here is a bin: http://jsbin.com/ipovon/1/edit

Comment: Can't your other handler simply check the bool variable ?

Comment: @dystroy The example is fictional, the condition is really based on the mousedown event properties but it seems bloated to post it here.

Comment: @David why don't you set some other condition if `bool` is true in mousedown and check *that* in `click`?

Comment: Why not just disable the button while the click actions are being performed?

Comment: @David Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, although, I'm not sure it's quite the answer you were looking for.  It's basically a double click function, if you set `bool=false;` initially.

```
var bool = true;

$('button').mousedown(function(e) {
  bool = !bool;
  if ( bool ) {
    $(this).unbind('click');
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    });
  }
});
```

**Update**

Also, you could pull the click function out of the `mousedown` like this, if you like:

```
var bool = true;
function buttonClick(){
  console.log('clicked');
}
$('button').mousedown(function(e) {
  bool = !bool;
  if ( bool ) {
    $(this).unbind('click');
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).click(buttonClick);
  }
});
```